# Atmospheric correction and difference(s) between ATCOR and FLAASH

Tags: atmospheric-correction, references, flaash

Talking about atmospheric correction, I'm interested in knowing the difference between ATCOR and FLAASH given that both are based on MODTRAN. Anyone happened to know this or have a recommended text?

Answer (score 1):

I have used ATCOR and FLAASH. Honestly,I feel FLAASH outputs better results, although it is hard to quantify. ATCOR will produce low corrected reflectance values.